# Incorporating local repository code changes to running container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and I have started working with docker from last week. There are a few things that confuse me a lot.

Regarding the basics, I know that in Docker, Docker File is used for creating Docker Images using the build command

Once a Docker image is built, it can be uploaded in a Docker registry

With Docker Image, any user can run the code in order to create Docker Containers

From the Docker Registry, users can get the Docker Image and build new containers whenever they want.

Now suppose, I have downloaded and built 3 images from docker repo and made one using dockerfile (all using 1 docker-compose.yml file).
My doubts - 
1) If I clone my teams'dev branch from git (made from master branch only and they have added their 1 feature in this new branch), then do I need to use docker-compose up. If yes then will my existing images will be modified or what will happen internally
2) I use exec -it name bash to do changes inside containers. How can saving my local changes and doing docker restart container_name get those changes (did my image get modified in this process)
3) When do we need to rebuild the image actually then using 'rebuild' command

Sorry if these questions sound like childish but believe me I have spent lot of time searching and figuring out the way things are working in docker.

Answer (score 3):

You should never use `docker exec` to make changes inside containers: those changes will be lost as soon as the container exits and is deleted.  `docker exec` is an extremely useful debugging tool but it should not be part of your core Docker workflow.  (It doesn't show up at all in the four steps in the first half of your question, for example.)

For local-development purposes, actually uploading an image to a registry is optional.  You can `docker build` an image, then immediately `docker run` it, without uploading it.

If you run `docker-compose up`, what exactly happens depends on whether the `docker-compose.yml` file has [`build:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) or [`image:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#image) lines.  If there are both, then when Compose builds an image, it will have the specified name and tag, which might overlap with an image in your registry.  An existing image is never modified, but only one image can have a given name and tag at a time, so if you do manually `docker-compose build` it could result in a previous image being hidden (`docker images` will show it with a tag of `<none>`).

When you do have local changes and you've rebuilt your image, `docker-compose up` knows to delete and recreate the existing container.  The new container will be based on the new image and will have the new code.  (Deleting and recreating a container this way is extremely routine, and Compose knows how to do it for a variety of other configuration changes as well.)

A workflow that's generally worked well for me is to develop a given service locally and get it fully passing its own unit tests, with no Docker involved at all.  Once you've gotten to that point, *then* run `docker-compose build` to get a new image and do integration testing in your local environment.  If that passes to your satisfaction, *then* commit to source control, and let your continuous-integration system build and push a Docker image from that.